# Can't seem to create "good" JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

Basically I have a loop. Every time the code from the loop gets executed, this happens:

```
json_data.append({object_name : [string1, string2]})
```

So I'm creating a lot of arrays, followed by 2 values inside each array.

After that I just do this:

```
json_file = json.dumps(json_data)
with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(json_file, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

The problem is the output I'm getting is the following:

```json
"[{\"cat\": [\"female\", \"fish\"]}, {\"pig\": [\"male\", \"carrots\"]}, {\"dog\": [\"male\", \"dogfood"]}]"
```

Now I think this is wrong because: It starts with double quotes, which indicates everything is a string and not JSON. After that in each object there's an escape sequence instead of quotes. How can I solve all of this?

Comment: Try this: `json.dump(json_data, f, ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: Read about [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), follow the Examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop dumping twice. You're generating JSON, and then encoding the resultant string as JSON.